# Minimal number of variables in a ZFC-undecidable sentence?

Tags: logic, set-theory, incompleteness

Let $\phi$ be a sentence of set theory. In Prenex form, $\phi$ can be written

$$
{\bf Q}_1 x_1 {\bf Q}_2 x_2 \ldots {\bf Q}_n x_n
\ \ \psi(x_1,x_2, \ldots ,x_n)  
$$

where each ${\mathbf Q}_i$ is one of the quantifiers $\forall$ or $\exists$, and $\psi$ is a function of the Boolean values $x_i \in x_j$ and $x_i=x_j$.

If we want $\phi$ to be undecidable in ZFC, what is the smallest 
possible value for $n$ ?

Edit : We assume that ZFC is consistent, of course, otherwise the question is uninteresting.

Comment: If $ZFC$ is not consistent, then all sentence are proveable in ZFC. So suppose $ZFC$ is consistent, by the incompleteness theorem, $Con(ZFC)$ is undecidable. $Con(ZFC)$ is roughly: for all strings, the string does not code a proof of $x \neq x$. Coding a proof is recursive, i.e. $\Delta_1^0$. In particular, using only one $\forall$ quantifier over $\omega$. The the "for all strings" part adds on another $\forall$ quantifier over $\omega$. Contracting quantifier, $Con(ZFC)$ has one $\forall$ quantifier. In fact, it is somewhat weaker since the quantification only needs to range of $\omega$.

Comment: @William So  $Con(ZFC)$ is $\Pi_1$ in the Levy hierarchy. Good point, but it does not answer my initial question that was about the number of quantifiers, not about the Levy hierarchy.

Comment: To emphasize Ewan's point: A $\Pi^0_1$ statement such as $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ has only one unbounded universal quantifier, but also carries many hidden (bounded) quantifiers. Using the DMPR theorem, it can be turned into a $\Pi_1$ statement, but many universal quantifiers are used now.

Comment: (Plus, we need to describe $\omega$ somehow, and this adds up.)

Comment: In the Levy Hierarchy, $Con(ZFC)$ is lower than $\Pi_1$, it is $\Pi_0 = \Sigma_0$. It has only bounded quantifiers. However, bounded quantifiers are short hand for expression consisting of quantifiers. So arithmetical formulas can have many quantifiers if you put them into prenex form.

Comment: @William Not quite $\Pi_0$. You need to define $\omega$ to bound the statement.

Comment: For a related similar question (in the context of $\mathsf{PA}$), see [here](http://math.andrej.com/2006/11/04/are-small-sentences-of-peano-arithmetic-decidable/).